# javascript string date from array and group by day and return new array per day

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I got a array of data the data is dates they are sorted per day.
Wat i want to get is the data grouped by date(day) and all the data of every day needs to be in new and separated array. my data can be short 1 date string in 1 day or very long month's or year

My data:

```
accountDateArray = [
Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:16 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:26 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:34 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Tue Jun 09 2020 15:40:31 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Tue Jun 09 2020 15:42:28 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Wed Jun 10 2020 00:06:50 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Wed Jun 10 2020 00:06:50 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Wed Jun 10 2020 08:10:51 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
Fri Jun 12 2020 10:59:21 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
...
]
```

What i want is:

```
[
 [
 Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:16 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
 Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:26 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
 Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:34 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
 ],
 [
 Tue Jun 09 2020 15:40:31 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
 Tue Jun 09 2020 15:42:28 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd),
 ],
  ...
]
```

My code

```
     let NewDateArray = [];
          for (let i in accountDateArray) {
            NewDateArray.push(accountDateArray[i].toString().substring(0, 10));
          }
          let unique = [...new Set(NewDateArray)];

          for (let i in accountDateArray) {
            for (let n in unique) {
              if (
                unique[n] === accountDateArray[i].toString().substring(0, 10)
              ) {
                console.log(accountDateArray[i]);
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: You can make use of `reduce()` to achieve your task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` function, I hope this will lead you to the right direction.

```js
var accountDateArray = ['Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:16 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:26 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Mon Jun 08 2020 19:47:34 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Tue Jun 09 2020 15:40:31 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Tue Jun 09 2020 15:42:28 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Wed Jun 10 2020 00:06:50 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Wed Jun 10 2020 00:06:50 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Wed Jun 10 2020 08:10:51 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)','Fri Jun 12 2020 10:59:21 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)',];

var result = Object.values(accountDateArray.reduce((acc, date)=>{
    const key = new Date(date).getDate();
    acc[key] = [...(acc[key] || []), date];
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! its what is was looking for